# Can a webserver basic auth be made GDPR/DSVGO conform

Tags: basic-authentication, gdprconsentform

If your root (or any other path) of your domain is restricted with a basic auth using .htaccess file the user does not get real HTML without a successfull login. Username and password might be personal information.

At least DSVGO enforces to put a privacy statement on every page. Also (not sure who rules this) every page must contain an imprint (at least in Germany).

When entering an url with a non-html based Basic Auth login form shown due to .htaccess like shown below, the user does not see any privacy statement or imprint nor any link to one.

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "restricted area"
AuthUserFile /path/to/the/directory/you/are/protecting/.htpasswd
require valid-user
```

[image]

Is this DSVGO / GDPR conform?
How can I make it conform if not - Especially if set for root access (http://example.com/)?